# Designing a memory overwrite detection tool

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am in the task of designing and coding a new memory-overwrite testing tool in Linux, which catches errors due to overwrites in dynamically allocated memory.

**One good way to do that is**, if user requests x bytes, then allocate x+r bytes. Using `mprotect` put no access to r bytes, so that if the user program runs to that part it will be halted generating a SIGSEGV.

But the problem in above case is, `mprotect` requires a mapped memory (`mmap`) and every time there is a `malloc` request mapping the x+r bytes is practically an overhead.

Can you suggest any other way? Or any code-snippet if you have worked on such tool ?

P.S: Can anyone share any design document of any such open source tool they know or have used?

Comment: Sound like you are rewriting efence, maybe you want to look at how they do it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: The procedure mentioned above by me is used by efence. It has a huge memory overhead. So no point in re-writing it.

Comment: valgrind? http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html

Answer (score 2):

One way is to allocate more memory and fill it with specific byte-patterns at the front and at the back, the user data would be between these red zones. On deallocation you check if the red zone patters are intact. [Identifying Memory Management Bugs Within Applications Using the libumem Library](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/libumem_library.html) explains it in more detail.

Comment: What is suppose we fill up with "As" and if the last overwrite is the same letter? What can be a unique filler?

Comment: Fill it with 0xdeadbeef for example. Probability of overwriting a byte with the same value is 1/256, for 4 bytes it is 1/256^4.

Comment: At the same time, the procedure you mentioned surely prevents writes, how about memory-read? It won't detect if the memory was attempted to read at that place, right?

Comment: Right. Presumably all allocated memory is memory used by the application in one way or another. On a low level one can't tell a valid read from invalid.

Comment: Up vote for the write-protection process, but sorry i can't accept the answer as it is not a full-proof method, protecting reads as well.

Comment: There is no full-proof method for that, otherwise it would have been implemented by now. Hardware access controls only work on whole pages. `valgrind` CPU simulation won't catch wrong accessed to allocated memory and stack.

Answer (score 1):

Not an open source product, but here is a [technical paper](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/CheckPointer.pdf) that describes in considerable detail how we implemented [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) for the C language.  CheckPointer will detect errors that Valgrind will not.

It is left as an exercise for the reader to do the same for C++ :-{

Comment: Thanks, an upvote for you for this useful link. Let me check it and get back to you in case of confusions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mprotect, you need to work by page.
Suppose a user wants x bytes, assume x<=4K (x>4K complicates it just a bit).
Allocate 8K, using mmap (which gives you aligned pages), use mprotect to write-protect the second page.
When returning to the user, don't give him a pointer to the first page, but p+3096-x.
Now he'll have exactly x bytes accessible, and will crash when trying to write after it.

Comment: And what happens if he tries to write "before" it?  C programs are full of pointer decrements, too.

Comment: @IraBaxter, You get good detection for either writes after the data (by putting the data at the end of the page) or writes before it (by putting data at the beginning). You can make it configurable, and run two tests. Or you can decide randomly on each allocation.